# error in creating jsp page using Jboss server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss

I installed `jdk1.8` and `jboss-eap-6.3`

After installed jboss-eap-6.3 I'm not able to create simplie jsp page

It giving error like

> Visual Page Editor has experimental support for Windows 64-bit.
>   Follow the link below to get details on how to install. Until then you can click on the Source tab to hide this error/info message

```
    org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.XulRunnerBundleNotFoundException: Bundle org.mozilla.xulrunner.win32.win32.x86_64 is not found.
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.getXulRunnerPath(XulRunnerBrowser.java:233)
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.browser.XulRunnerBrowser.<init>(XulRunnerBrowser.java:117)
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner.editor.XulRunnerEditor.<init>(XulRunnerEditor.java:128)
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.XulRunnerEditor2.<init>(XulRunnerEditor2.java:23)
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.mozilla.MozillaEditor.createPartControl(MozillaEditor.java:594)
        at org.jboss.tools.vpe.editor.VpeEditorPart.createVisualEditor(VpeEditorPart.java:813)
        at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.pageChange(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1101)
        at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.createPages(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:321)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:983)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1251)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:692)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1126)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3182)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$23(WorkbenchPage.java:3104)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$9.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3086)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3081)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3045)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3035)
        at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:541)
        at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:500)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.wizard.NewJSPWizard$1.run(NewJSPWizard.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)`
```

Answer (score 11):

My eclipse is Luna. On the page of JBoss developers they sent the solution pro problem:

1. Go Install New Software;
2. Enter the address http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/integration/luna/core/xulrunner/
3. Select all dependencies and click "OK".

Solved the problem for me.

Comment: this is a worked for me too ,this is the right solution not the above one

Answer (score 0):

you try to run with a 32-bit JVM then it will be able to load the xulrunner UI even on Windows 64.